# select * from table_name where column like '&nbsp'

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find records containing html code such as '&nbsp' But when I try to run the `select * from table_name where column like '&nbsp%'`
   I got prompt asking for the value of nbsp. I guess the database thinks that nbsp is a parameter. I am wondering if the is an escape character so that I can tell the database that "&" is part of my query string. I tryed '\&nbsp' but didn't work.

My environment is Oracle 9i with sqlplus client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[SQL Plus FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#How_does_one_disable_interactive_prompting_in_SQL.2APlus.3F)

e.g.

```
SET ESCAPE '\'
SELECT '\&abc' FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 11):

Easier way:

SET DEFINE OFF

See:
[SET DEFINE](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/set_define.html)

Comment: This works very well too. But I saw another answer first, so I had to mark the other one as answer. But one up vote for you :)

Answer (score 2):

The backslash should work, but I think you need to start your query with

```
SET ESCAPE ON
```

Comment: Duplicate answer to the other one, but saw it was only 5 mins different from the one that's been upvoted more, and this one was actually first.  That's rough voting... here's my +1

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL, you would use:

`BEGIN select <Column> from <Table_name> into <Variable> where <Column> LIKE '\&nbsp\%' ESCAPE '\'; END
/`

**Resources:**

[Wilcards in SQL on PSOUG.org](http://psoug.org/reference/wildcards.html)

[LIKE Condition in Oracle® Database SQL Language Reference 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142)