# How to insert & in oracle using toad?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select * from table_name where column like '&nbsp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957436/select-from-table-name-where-column-like-nbsp)

How do you insert the `& symbol` as data in an Oracle database, using Toad?  Example:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> 
  (column)
VALUES 
  ('AT & T');
```

When executing script asking new value for T...

Comment: It's because the `&` indicates BIND variable when Toad (or SQLPlus) executes the script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select * from table_name where column like '&nbsp'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957436/select-from-table-name-where-column-like-nbsp). Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus.  There are numerous duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+%22set+define+off%22

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
insert into my_table values ('AT &' || 'T');
```

You can also try using:

```
set define off;
```

In your environment so `&Something` won't be treated as if it is an input variable. But I don't know where to put that in TOAD.

Comment: Such a weird :-S Experienced the same issue and solved it in the same way, but may be there is an option to turn off placeholders look up?

Comment: @zerkms: yes. `set define off` in **SQLPlus**. Don't know if it will work in **TOAD** though. But 100% agreed: it's weird. I guess it's still there for backward compatibility. This feature might be at least 25 years old. :-)

Comment: if define off then no need of || in this 'AT &' || 'T'

Answer (score 4):

`SET DEFINE OFF` will stop sqlplus interpreting & this way.

this will also work

```
set define off;
insert into tablename values( 'AT & T');
```

Comment: Try this steps:

Go to View → Options → SQL Editor → and uncheck the value Scan statements for bound variables before execution

Comment: Search for

Execute/Compile options -> "Prompt for substitution variables" and uncheck the same

tell if any of this works for you ?

Comment: The question was about Toad and not SQLPlus.

Comment: In Toad you can turn it off in View / Options / Execute/Compile => "Substitution Variable Prompting" set to "None"